# is it possible to parse jwt token claim without secret when using rust jsonwebtoken

Tags: rust, jwt

I am trying to using rust [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/Keats/jsonwebtoken) to parse a jwt token, this is the code looks like:

```
use jsonwebtoken::{decode, DecodingKey, Validation};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Claims {
    user_id: i32,
    device_id: String,
    app_id: String,
    exp: usize,
    pin: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let token ="eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjkyLCJkZXZpY2VJZCI6ImYzOTQyZjU2MzUzZmFkODQyOTU2ZjQwZDNmMjY3Y2MxIiwiYXBwSWQiOiJ4U1c1YTRCYlZCIiwiZXQiOjAsInBpZCI6MTIsImV4cCI6MTY4NTI3NDMzM30.4uMrxm9iYt940RDL6UWFw2iN5y3p27w6H4ALtBBiE1ESnuyqBqznEIs1f240omN7bC7CpQoVhi73IZmxVTJjwA";
    let token_data = decode::<Claims>(
        token,
        &DecodingKey::from_secret("your-secret".as_ref()),
        &Validation::default(),
    );
    match token_data {
        Ok(_data) => println!("Claims:{:?}", _data.claims),
        Err(e) => println!("Error:{}", e),
    }
}
```

and this is the `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "rust-learn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.64"
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.2", features = ["json"]}
rust_wheel = { git = "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/rust_wheel.git", branch = "diesel2.0" }
jsonwebtoken = "8.3.0"
```

the problem is, the jwt parse need a secret. is it possible to parse the jwt token without secret in this rust jsonwebtoken lib? I did not know where to find the secret. I have pasted the token to online jwt token parser, it could parse success without the secret.

Comment: Seems the library does not support decoding a JWT without verification. If you really just need the payload, you can just split the token by `.`, base64 decode the second part and parse it as json ...

Comment: @derpirscher It does support this, the API documentation just makes it difficult to discover how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Keats/jsonwebtoken/issues/277), you can do this by supplying an empty decoding key and turning off signature validation entirely.  The sample code provided on the linked issue is:

```
let key = DecodingKey::from_secret(&[]);
let mut validation = Validation::new(Algorithm::HS256);
validation.insecure_disable_signature_validation();

let data: TypeYouWant = decode(&token, &key, &validation)?;
```

The API you're looking for is [`Validation::insecure_disable_signature_validation()`](https://docs.rs/jsonwebtoken/latest/jsonwebtoken/struct.Validation.html#method.insecure_disable_signature_validation).

Note that you may also want to turn off [`validate_exp`](https://docs.rs/jsonwebtoken/latest/jsonwebtoken/struct.Validation.html#structfield.validate_exp).